# Smaller XPath with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm processing XML documents with XPath where the case of specific elements can differ from one document to the next (don't ask; I don't control the document generation).

In order to process this, one of my XPath queries looks like this:

```
//group[group='Foo']/subGroup[sub='Bar' or Sub='Bar'] | //group[group='Foo']/SubGroup[sub='Bar' or Sub='Bar']
```

Note that the `subGroup` element can occur as either `subGroup` or `SubGroup`, and the `sub` element can appear as either `sub` or `Sub`.

Is there any way to shorten this XPath?

I have multiple queries that are similar to this but effectively duplicate or expand the `sub` portion (e.g. `[a='b' and (sub='Bar' or Sub='Bar')]`.  The `subGroup` and `SubGroup` differences and the `sub` and `Sub` differences are present in most queries even if the `//group[group='Foo']` sections are different.

Comment: Is this in `XPath 1.0` or `XPath 1.1`? Makes quite a difference..

Comment: I'm using VTD-XML, which says it supports XPath 1.0 with some XPath 2.0 features.  Namely, it says upper-case(), lower-case() and ends-with() from 2.0 are supported.

Comment: for XPath 1.0 you could use the transform function i.c.m. local-name(). This is assuming the conditional axis are attributes instead of elements, but the idea remains the same. //group[@group='Foo']/*[translate(local-name(),'s','S')='SubGroup'][@sub='Bar' or @Sub='Bar']

Comment: It's all elements; no attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, its less long but certainly not less ugly

```
//group[group='Foo']/*[self::subGroup | self::SubGroup][sub='Bar' or Sub='Bar']
```

Other variants would rely on `translate()` and `name()`, like Marvin Smit outlines in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524079/smaller-xpath-with-multiple-conditions/19524425#comment28965467_19524079).

Comment: Not less ugly, no, but definitely helped.

Comment: @Steven Just a quick note about `*[self::subGroup | self::SubGroup]`: Actually it *should* be `*[self::subGroup or self::SubGroup]`, since the union (`|`) produces a node-set rather than a Boolean. However, it is a union of mutually exclusive nodes (the node cannot both be `<subGroup>` and `<SubGroup>`), so it ends up being a node-set that either contains exactly one node or is empty. The non-empty node-set evaluates to `true`, so we can use it as a predicate here. It's really a small hack to save one character. ;)